# Jquery: Possible to dynamically change source of Autocomplete widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Greetings,

I am using the official Autocomplete jquery widget and am having troubles dynamically changing a variable (selectType) I'm passing via the query string.  The variable would change depending upon which option is selected via a select box.

```
$(function() {
var selectType = $('#selectType option:selected').attr("value");    


$("#selectType").change(function(){
    selectType = $('#selectType option:selected').attr("value");
    alert (selectType);  // alerts the right value for debugging
});

$("#address").autocomplete({
    source: "ajaxSearchForClientAddress.php?selectType="+selectType,
    minLength: 3
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try actually changing the `source` option of the autocomplete on the change event.

```
$(function () {
    var select = $( "#selectType" ),
        options = select.find( "option" ),
        address = $( "#address" );

    var selectType = options.filter( ":selected" ).attr( "value" );
    address.autocomplete({
        source: "ajaxSearchForClientAddress.php?selectType=" + selectType,
        minLength: 3
    });

    select.change(function () {
        selectType = options.filter( ":selected" ).attr( "value" );
        address.autocomplete( "option", "source", "ajaxSearchForClientAddress.php?selectType=" + selectType );
    });
});
```