# jquery-ui autocomplete sporadic behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Below is the code for my autocomplete.  The problem is that it *mostly* works.  Say I have a bunch of results that are like test1, test2, test3, etc.  If I type "t" they popup, when I put an e in "te" they disappear.  Then if I put in the "s" it narrows it down further.  it's not always the second letter either.  It just seems sporadic.  Please help.  I have confirmed the data coming back is solid, so it's nothing on the backend.

```
        //Server autocomplete
        $("#txtSearchServer").keyup(function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'edit/EditService.svc/SearchServers',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'term': $("#txtSearchServer").val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var listServers = [];
                    $.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        ///working here to do server autocomplete!!!!!!!
                        listServers.push(item.ServerName);
                        $("#txtSearchServer").autocomplete({
                            source: listServers
                        });
                    });
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Servers for autocomplete!');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: why are you initiating autocomplete every time ajax succeeds, on top of the keyup event? autocomplete should be initiated once on what ever you are applying it to.

Comment: So it's dynamic based on what you type in.  Each time you type a letter it queries the webservice for the complete value in the text box and returns the top 10 matching names.

Comment: (note I've never used the jquery-ui autocomplete before...)

Comment: So if I initiate autocomplte outside of the ajax query and specify the source as listServers, all I have to do is update that variable and it will automatically update the results?

Comment: what i mean, is that you should have source: listServers, listServers defined outside autocomplete and ajax call, and update it on every success of ajax call. Basically you have autocomplete applying its events on your input field and you are applying you keyup event, and overwriting that variable all that time, by creating new instances of autocomplete after every keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are doing asp.net

SO this should work for you:

```
function AutocompleteJSONParse(data) {
    var rows = new Array();
    var rowData = null;
    for (var i = 0, dataLength = data.length; i < dataLength; i++) {
        rowData = data[i];
        rows[i] = {
            value: rowData.ServerName,
            label: rowData.ServerName
        };
    }
    return rows;
};
$("#txtSearchServer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var pString = '{"term":"' + request.term + '"}';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit/EditService.svc/SearchServers',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "jsond",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            converters: {
                "json jsond": function(msg) {
                    return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
                }
            },
            data: pString,
            success: function(data) {
                var rows = AutocompleteJSONParse(data);
                response(rows);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Servers for autocomplete!');
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 1000
});
```

Comment: I didn't test this code exactly, but after research it's the basic conclusion I came up with. The ajax call needs to be inside the autocomplete source, and that's what I did and it works.  Thanks!

Comment: One key element with your asp.net is the converter.  This is backwards compatible with older asp.net versions as well as the newer ones so that the (data.d) you have simply gets converted - it detects the presence and makes it consistent.  I used the parse rather than the .map as it gives me flexibility to use a very complex json object on the source end and map multiple values for other purposes for instance.  It does not cache the potential data however as I have been using this with nearly 100,000 values in my data source with a multiple term match, so you might want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: https://gist.github.com/1140631 that should solve it.

EDIT: I was wondering also why are you dynamically prefetching results, can't you get full list right away? Or is it to much data?

Comment: Okay I pasted that code exactly and every keyup it does the query which comes back ok but I never get an autocomplete popup.

Comment: can you set up your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ please and post link to it once you are done.

Comment: also take a look at this post, it explaines how to change source of autocomplete plgugin dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399139/jquery-possible-to-dynamically-change-source-of-autocomplete-widget I have also update my source code to reflect this.