# jQuery autocomplete widget how to pass current value as parameter to webservice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement the jquery autocomplete widget in my jquery mobile page to suggest a list of cities.
When the user enters more 2 or more characters I want to pass the current typed text to a webservice and return all matches and show these in a selectbox.
However, I don't know how to pass the current typed text and as a results an empty string passed for parameter "prefixText", and in that case my webservice just returns all results.

How can I update the prefixText paramter in my source call each time the user enters a new character?

```
<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="cities">Cities: </label>
    <input id="cities" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
</div><!-- End demo -->


$(function () {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }

    $("#cities").autocomplete({
        source: "http://www.mydomain.com/service.svc/cities/?cid=1&pid=3&prefixText=" + $('#cities').val(),
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);*/
        },
        search: function (event, ui) {
            alert($('#cities').val());              
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to your input field a listener through `.on(...)`. I made you an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Calavoow/q8RuD/1/

I'm not quite sure if keyup is the right event to bind to but it works on PC. You could also bind to 'change' if it doesn't work for you. But then it won't update each keypress.
When you've done that, you can reapply your autocomplete. See the following answer:
[Jquery: Possible to dynamically change source of Autocomplete widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399139/jquery-possible-to-dynamically-change-source-of-autocomplete-widget)