# Get .val() from a seleted item in a dropbox that was populated by Ajax (is Blank at source code!)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I've 3 fields in my form: State, City and district;

When I select the state, the city dropbox is populated with the relative data.
Then I need to autocomplete District passing as parameter the cityID

This is what is look like:

```
$(document).ready(function()     {
    $('#AdDistrict').autocomplete(
    {

    source: "autocomplete/fetch?model=district&field=name&city=" + $("#AdCityId").val(),
    minLength: 2
    });
  });
```

But that `$("#AdCityId").val()` is blank, and if I look at the source code I've nothing in to `<options>` but appears on the page.

I've tried use

```
$("#AdCityId").val(), 
$("#AdCityId option:selected").val()
```

But I always get "undefined". I think the problem is because in the source, my select looks like it:

```
<div class="input select required"><label for="AdCityId">City</label><select name="data[Ad][city_id]" id="AdCityId">
<option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>
</select></div>
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where using a function as source would make sense.

```
source: function(request,response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "autocomplete/fetch?model=district&field=name&city=" + $("#AdCityId").val(),
        data: { term: request.term },
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the .autocomplete() source in the onchange event of the city dropdown like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399139/jquery-possible-to-dynamically-change-source-of-autocomplete-widget)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <option value="">Selecione a Cidade</option>
```

The option has its value set to "" so it returns exactly that. If you want the text inbetween change it to

```
   <option>Selecione a Cidade</option>
```