# Trigger Jquery Autocomplete to select with dynamic added value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have this input witch get it´s value from PHP.

```
<input id="autocomplete_obj_nr" value="<?php echo $obj_nr;?>"/>
```

How can i trigger Autocomplete to select that value when page is loaded?

**I´ve tried:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#autocomplete_obj_nr').autocomplete("select");
```

> no such method 'select' for autocomplete widget instance

```
$('input#autocomplete_obj_nr').autocomplete("option", "select");
```

**EDIT**
I do not wan´t to change source. I just wan´t to trigger a select on a value added by PHP.
It works by fetching a $_GET in the URL.

Comment: Looking [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) I don't see any "select" method as well

Comment: I´m able to use "search" but not "select"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: Possible to dynamically change source of Autocomplete widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399139/jquery-possible-to-dynamically-change-source-of-autocomplete-widget)

Comment: @AZinkey Naaaah ?!

Comment: @BjörnC because "search" is a defined method, while "select" is an event. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select