# JQuery Autocomplete source not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using `jquery-ui autocomplete` plugin.

Here is how I've instantiated the autocomplete plugin.

```
//autofill
$( "#TextArea" ).autocomplete({
    source: "search.php?option="+ option.toLowerCase(),
    minLength: 3
});
```

On dropdown change, i am trying to change the option :

```
$('#Options').on('change',  function() {
        option = this.value.toLowerCase();
        var teaxtarea = $('#TextArea');
        //this is supposed to change the source string when the option value changes.
        teaxtarea.autocomplete( "option", "source", "search.php?option="+ option);
    }
});
```

I got the code to update the source string from the question below.

[Jquery: Possible to dynamically change source of Autocomplete widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399139/jquery-possible-to-dynamically-change-source-of-autocomplete-widget)

However, this solution doesn't seem to work for me.

I still get the first selected option even if I change the option in the dropdown.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you changing the source of data while user types? `option = this.value.toLowerCase(); "search.php?option="+ option` isn't this the same as previous `"search.php?option="+ option.toLowerCase(),` so what change in results are you expecting?

Comment: Reviewing the examples more deeply, I see that they are updating source upon a specific change. You may want to use "function" source anyways as you can ensure that browser is not caching values with a more complex AJAX Call.

Comment: @TJ , I have a dropdown menu and a text area. #options is the dropdown menu and #textarea is the text field. What i need is, to get autofill suggestions in the textarea according to the value selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest the following:

```
$("#TextArea").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp){
      var option = $('#Options option:selected').val().toLowerCase();
      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "search.php",
        data: {
          option: option,
          term: req.term
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          resp(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 3
});
```

I think one issue is that if `#Options` is a `<select>` element, you need to find the selected child element:

```
$("#Options option:selected")
```

This ensures that you have the proper object and then you can call `.val()` upon it.

That may resolve the issue for you. If not, continue on.

Second, to ensure you are not caching, we can perform a more manual source capture.

> When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must support CORS). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a `term` field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results.

So we replicate the same functionality with some added settings. So each time source is checked, the options will be checked and the term will be sent. We'll get the data back in JSON and send back to Autocomplete to be displayed.